# When I try to echo a posted string, the output is a boolean

Tags: php, html, forms, post, isset

I am trying to better my PHP skills and when I POST last name & first name, the echo outputs `1 1`. No matter what I put, the echo is `1 1`. Why is my code doing this?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    if (isset($_POST['firstname'])&& isset($_POST['lastname'])){
        $firstname=isset($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname=isset($_POST['lastname']);
        echo $lastname;
        echo $firstname;
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="practice2.php" method="post" name="user" >
            Please Enter your First Name: <br>
            <input type="text" name= "firstname"id="firstname">
            <br>
            Please Enter your Last Name: <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">

            <input type="submit" name="Submit">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it outputs 1 1 because you're telling it that it's set. You may have wanted to use a ternary operator instead and would cut down your code by 60%. This question has been asked many times already.

Answer (score 1):

the `isset` method returns a boolean, which when printed, results in showing you a 1. what you want is:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])&& isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];

    echo $lastname;
    echo $firstname;
}
```

You've already checked if they are set in your `if` statement, there's no reason to check again within it.

You can see the behavior of your original code more easily by trying

```
# this will output "1". isset is returning "true" in your original example
echo true;
```

Comment: why doesn't it return a boolean when declare it in the if statement?

Comment: @AaronNettles your if statement just evaluates to true or false - the result of which isn't set to anything. If its true, it executes the code within, if false, it does not.

Comment: ahhhhh I see @Erik the isset function just returns true or false because it is just checking the statement. Make so much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

To compliment other answers given where they have already explained the problem at hand, am submitting the following in order to show how you can cut down your code by 70%.

You can replace this entire block:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])&& isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $firstname=isset($_POST['firstname']); // issue has been addressed about this
    $lastname=isset($_POST['lastname']); // issue has been addressed about this
    echo $lastname;
    echo $firstname;
}
```

with and using a ternary operator along with an echo, all rolled up into one
(*echoing/checking/assigning*):

```
echo $firstname=isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
echo $lastname=isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
```

Or using `!empty()`

```
echo $firstname=!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
echo $lastname=!empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
```

---

If you want to keep the values and echo'd inside the inputs, you can do and use a ternary operator as a value:

Sidenote: This will only work if you've used the ternary operator as shown above.

```
Please Enter your First Name: <br>
<input type="text" name= "firstname"id="firstname" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''; ?>">
<br>
Please Enter your Last Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : ''; ?>">
```

To read up on the ternary operator, visit:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

With `isset()` you check whether a value has been set, you will not get its value, though. It returns a boolean -- in your case `true`, which is `echo`ed as 1.

Instead of

```
$firstname=isset($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname=isset($_POST['lastname']);
```

try

```
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
```

and you should get the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

step 1 : check whether the button is submit or not, if submit.
step 2 : Get the value from textbox using $_POST[''].
step 3 : echo it

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];


        echo $firstname . " " . $lastname;

}
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form action="practice2.php" method="post" name="user" >
                Please Enter your First Name: <br>
                <input type="text" name= "firstname"id="firstname">
                <br>
                Please Enter your Last Name: <br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">

                <input type="submit" name="Submit">

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```